# Authorize attribute created controller for non-authorized users

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a controller with Authorize attribute. I expected the controller will not be created in case user is not authorized. But seems like it does. Is there any way to change this behaviour and make Authorize generated 401 response without creating the control itself?

Why do I need this? I have some admin-oriented controllers which are targeted on authenticated users only. It has some logic in a base controller's constructor. Currently I have to check if User is null their which seems a waste.

Answer (score 0):

You can derive from `AuthorizeAttribute` and handle it the way you want. The request will hit this overridden method first to give you an opportunity to decide whether to allow the request to be served further or to reject it. You can also optionally ignore a particular method like Login by adding `AllowAnonymous` attribute or define your own attribute by deriving from `Attribute` class.

A working example is below:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class RdbiAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Verifies that the logged in user is a valid organization user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext"></param>
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        Guard.ArgumentNotNull(filterContext, "filterContext");
        Guard.ArgumentNotNull(filterContext.Controller, "filterContext.Controller");

        bool skipAuthorization = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(
            typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), inherit: true)
                                 || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(
                                     typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), inherit: true);

        if (skipAuthorization)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name))
            throw new AuthenticationException("User must be logged in to access this page.");

        var controller = filterContext.Controller as BaseController;
        if (controller != null)
        {
            var user = controller.GetUser();

            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Logged in user {0} is not a valid user", filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name));
            }
        }

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I got right the code you provided, filterContext.Controller already contains an instance of a Controller. So whatever I write inside OnAuthorization it won't change the fact that Controller is already instantiated.

Comment: I don't understand why do you care whether controller instantiated or not. If you handle the request, you can return appropriate response (401) to user and he will not get access any resource he is not authorized to. Am i missing your requirement?