# Use authentication of existing ASP.NET MVC 5 Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I've created a ASP.NET MVC 5 web app with the following tutorial:
[Create a secure ASP.NET MVC 5 web app with log in, email confirmation and password reset (C#)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset)

I left the `Startup.Auth.cs` class pretty much unchanged, except removing the two factor settings.

Now in a second ASP.NET MVC 5 web app, i would like to use the authentication of the first app. Both apps running on the same machine. I have created a `machineKey` entry in `Web.Config` for both apps:

```
  <system.web>
    <machineKey decryptionKey="8A0AF0BC123A17C7B71C29E1F8FF8EAEDF8DB52EA6xxxxxx"
                validationKey="8953BFD2FBF9098FEB8D3447F2D4A262E4090804DFB1D42731A532026943C22673C060333BF1F33BBD5A223F487AA8131DB7512A18AFD3DBBC78A0E955xxxxxx" />
```

Now i'm struggling with the configuration of the `Startup.Auth.cs` class. I tried to use `OnApplyRedirect` as described here:
[Login page on different domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21275399/login-page-on-different-domain)

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login"),
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/account/logout"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider { OnApplyRedirect = ApplyRedirect },
        });
        app.Run(context =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        });
    }
    private static void ApplyRedirect(CookieApplyRedirectContext context)
    {
        Uri absoluteUri;
        if (Uri.TryCreate(context.RedirectUri, UriKind.Absolute, out absoluteUri))
        {
            var path = PathString.FromUriComponent(absoluteUri);
            if (path == context.OwinContext.Request.PathBase + context.Options.LoginPath)
                context.RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44301/Account/Login" +
                new QueryString(
                context.Options.ReturnUrlParameter,
                context.Request.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
        }
        context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
    }
}
```

The second app does correctly redirect to the login page of the first app when accessing a secure page, but even after the login, I'm still not authenticated correctly. What am I missing? What exactly has to be defined in `LoginPath` and `LogoutPath`? Those two paths do not exist in the second app.

Comment: Machine key is not used in Identity framework - this is a wrong direction.

Comment: I wasn't sure about the machine key, thanks. What would be the 'right' direction then?