# Specifying custom external login page using OWIN and ACS WSFedAuth

Tags: owin, acs, ws-federation

I have a web application that uses ACS to federate multiple identity providers which I'm trying to migrate to use OWIN. I have a custom login page in a separate application (that shares a SSO experience with mine) which I was able to specify using the *issuer* attribute in the *wsfederation* configuration element in my existing pre-OWIN setup.

I've tried to replicate this behaviour using OWIN, but no matter what I try, an unauthenticated request is redirected to the standard (ugly) ACS login page. Here's how I've configured the middleware components:

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnResponseSignIn = ctx => TransformClaims(ctx.OwinContext.Authentication.User, loggingService)
    },
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["security:slidingExpirationMins"])),
    SlidingExpiration = true,
});

app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
    MetadataAddress = "https://mylogin.accesscontrol.windows.net/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml",
    Wtrealm = siteUrl,
    Wreply = siteUrl,
    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
});
```

The *LoginPath* property of the *CookieAuthenticationOptions* object won't work as it's not in the same application.

Any help with how I would specify the external login URL would be appreciated!

Comment: This answer has helped http://stackoverflow.com/a/21278878/3198687 - However now I need to provide the WsFedAuth wctx somehow...

Comment: Did you get the solution?  I am looking  for same thing. Could you post your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting to Passive the WSFederation middleware AuthenticationMode, otherwise it will keep intercepting outgoing 401s.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Any idea where would I specify the custom login URL?