# asp.net identity multipe user login

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

Hi I wonder if it is possible to have multiple login page for two difference site in same web application by using asp.net identity

For eg there are administrator login page and normal user login page. Once user login to admin already. user also allow to login to normal user page again without logout admin site. Btw There will be two difference of username

Does anyone has any idea how to do it ? Is this the limitation on asp.net identity to only allow one login page in the entire asp.net ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Late but might help someone. According to [Pinpoint Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21278878/1030977) on a similar question, You can do something like this in Startup class with customization:

```
    using System;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
    using Microsoft.Owin;
    using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
    using Owin;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
```

## Then add a "RedirectIfAdmin" to Provider

```
public partial class Startup {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
        // Basic for site guest
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/Logout"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider {
                OnApplyRedirect = RedirectIfAdmin,
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
   }
```

## And implement it to catch any string or parameter

```
    private static void RedirectIfAdmin(CookieApplyRedirectContext context)
    {
        // If Url contains 
        Uri absoluteUri;
        if (Uri.TryCreate(context.RedirectUri, UriKind.Absolute, out absoluteUri))
        {
            string path = context.Request.PathBase + context.Request.Path + context.Request.QueryString;
            if (path.Contains("/administration")) { 
                context.RedirectUri = "/administration/login.aspx" +
                new QueryString(context.Options.ReturnUrlParameter, context.Request.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
            }
        }

        context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks i will look for it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to login with Admin account and next login with user account you can just access the website with other browser or on private mode. I don't know what you want to do but if it's just for testing you can do this.